# Error in uploading .bacpac file from on-premise to azure

Tags: sql-server

I have downloaded ".bacpac" from the resource and i have successfully imported it in "Microsoft SQL Server Studio 2014" using data-tier application. But when i am trying to upload the same file from the "Microsoft SQL Server Studio" to Azure, it's throwing the following error.

It's showing operation failed at "creating database on target". When i am clicking the error link it's showing:

> An exception occured while executing a Transact -SQL statement or batch.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Connectioninfo)
>   Additional Information
>   'Web' is not a valid database edition in this version of sql server.(Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 40633)

Answer (score 4):

[The Web and Business Azure SQL Database tiers have been retired by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn741330.aspx).

Currently, SQL Server Management Studio 2014 only presents the Web and Business tiers as options when deploying a database to Azure, both of which will be rejected with the "not a valid database edition" message.

The current CTP of SQL Server Management Studio, which can be downloaded from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt238290.aspx), does allow you to select the newer Basic/Standard/Premium tiers when deploying a database to Azure, which should work and not produce the error described above.

Answer (score 0):

When you choose the option to deploy the database to Azure in SQL Server Management Studio it will prompt you for deployment settings. e.g. where you would have provided you database credentials. One of the values specified in that window is "Edition of Windows Azure SQL Database" and this may have defaulted to "Web". This could be the reason you are getting the error. Try changing this setting to a more suitable value, e.g. "Standard", and re-deploying the database to Azure.